# How can I record and save audio in QT C++?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, recording

I am trying to record and save audio file using `Qt` `c++` and here is my code for this purpose.

```
QAudioRecorder * audioRecorder = new QAudioRecorder();

if(audioRecorder->state() == audioRecorder->StoppedState)
{
    // Set recording Settings
    QAudioEncoderSettings settings;
    settings.setCodec("audio/pcm");     // Not sure what to put here
    settings.setSampleRate(16000);
    settings.setBitRate(32);
    settings.setQuality(QMultimedia::HighQuality);
    settings.setEncodingMode(QMultimedia::ConstantQualityEncoding);

    audioRecorder->setEncodingSettings(settings);

    //Set Audio Input
    audioRecorder->setAudioInput(audioRecorder->defaultAudioInput());

    // Sets Output location where to store the file
    QUrl url("hello.wav");
    audioRecorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile("hello.wav"));
    audioRecorder->setContainerFormat("mp3");

    audioRecorder->record();

    qDebug()<<audioRecorder->state();
}
else
{
    qDebug()<<"stopped";
}
```

But it does not save any file rather shows the message `no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.audiosource"`.
How can I save the audio file?

Answer (score 0):

You should install some [Qt Multimedia Backend](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Multimedia_Backends) - check this list (proper for Qt version that you use) and select backend for your operating system.

Comment: thanks @trivelt, the source you provided is quite tough to start with. Can you suggest any beginner level resource.

Comment: Hm, which operating system and Qt version do you use?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04 and QT version is 5.7.  @trivelt

Comment: Do you have gstreamer installed? If not try this:
`sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0`

Comment: Also, as I remember, for some QtMultimedia features you also need to install other gstreamer plugins. If you type `sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0` and double-click `tab` you can see available plugins and try to install some of them.

Comment: Could you try install libgstreamer0.10-* and gstreamer0.10-* instead of 1.0?